# C++ Will copy elision happen when returning a temporary object

Tags: c++

If I understand correctly copy elision will happen if an object is returned like this:

```
CSomeObject getObject(){

    //....
    //....
    return CSomeObject(...);
}
```

Is it safe to assume that copy elision will also happen here:

```
CSomeObject getObject(){

    CSomeObject some_object;
    some_object.setStuff();
    some_object.setMoreStuff();
    //....
    //....
    return some_object;
}

CSomeObject some_object = getObject();
```

There is only one return statement and always the same temporary object is returned. What about when the return is delegated / indirect:

```
CSomeObject getObject_2(){
    //....
    return getObject();
}

CSomeObject some_object = getObject_2();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C++ Will copy elision happen when returning a temporary object" - it may. It's not guaranteed until C++17 (and even there, certain conditions apply). But, most compilers will elide the copy.